# Unexpected network traffic showing in Chrome Task Manager

Tags: google-chrome

I'm looking at a web page open in Chrome browser (Version 32.0.1700.14 beta-m Aura).

Javascript on that page is unendingly changing the `src` of an `img` tag between 7 different images. Using Fiddler, I can see that those images are pulled over the network when they are first accessed.

After loading them, there is no more network traffic.

However, when I open the Task Manager in the browser, I'm seeing activity in the "Network" column for that tab whenever the image is being changed.

Why is that?  There is no actual network traffic (according to Fiddler), so why is Chrome indicating that there is?  Can the "Network" column be trusted?

Comment: The site where I saw this happening is here: http://justinbicknell.com/mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try any other methods of monitor network-activity/bandwidth? The screenshot below shows what the *Networking* tab and a bandwidth-monitor program see while the [page in question](http://justinbicknell.com/mo) is loaded and swapping images.

As you can see, after the initial loading, there is essentially no other network activity happening, while Chrome’s task manager is reporting phantom network activity.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager and bandwidth monitor showing no network activity while Chrome shows activity]

Curiously, there does [not seem to be any mention](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=task%20manager%20network%20column&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified%20Stars) of this phantom bandwidth usage, and in fact, there are a couple of reports of [insufficient](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125205) or even [*no* network activity](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=184753) being shown.

It’s not clear why this could be happening (I can neither find any documentation to explain it, nor fathom any rational explanation), so it seems like a bug. As such, I have taken the liberty to file a [bug-report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=330931).

Comment: Well they have confirmed the bug and determined its cause—but it’s “untriaged”. Hopefully they’ll have it fixed soon.

Comment: They’ve closed the issue as “fixed”, so hopefully it no longer does this.

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the opposite problem
Chrome Browser high Network Activity even during idle  :( fix )
(we may get a fat internet bill) only thing that worked for me is this:

- right-click on  Chrome icon  SHORTCUT
- click   PROPERTIES
- add   -DISABLE-BACKGROUND-NETWORKING  at the end of  TARGET:
- click  APPLY

old  TARGET:

"C:\ .......... .....\chrome.exe"

new  TARGET:

"C:\ .......... .....\chrome.exe"  -DISABLE-BACKGROUND-NETWORKING

Google chrome using too much bandwidth? 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/dDhHrR2QNWc